# can't use fetch api to post wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, fetch

I try to use Postman to do this and it work great, but when I use javascript to fetch the post method I found this error.

[image: https://sv1.picz.in.th/images/2019/01/19/9F95La.png]

This is my code

[image: https://sv1.picz.in.th/images/2019/01/19/9F9Okq.png]

and this is my .htaccess

[image: https://sv1.picz.in.th/images/2019/01/19/9F9Dx0.png]

Comment: You should paste the relevant code necessary to reproduce / show your problem instead of images

Comment: Have you tried switching content-type to application/json since that is the data you are passing?

Comment: @imvain2 yes I have tried already, found same result.

Comment: What are the exact headers that work for you in Postman?

Comment: every thing same the fetch in javascript 

https://sv1.picz.in.th/images/2019/01/19/9FizEI.png

@Aioros

Comment: Since you're getting an authorization error, are you sure you are sending the same token?

Comment: Yes, I have checked, It​ send same token.​ @Aioros